# background service android without notify

Tags: android, service, background

I need to create a service Android, once you quit the application, the service is not closed, but no notification. I used startForegound camando but this requires a more prominent notice.
Thank you all for the replies

Comment: Please post your code it will be useful to recognize your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `START_STICKY` to make your Service running continuously.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handleCommand(intent);
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}
```